# Open new tab when click on a div Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am developping an angular project my problem is that i want when i click into a div i open a new tab but it doesn't work for me.
It worked for `<a>`.
Can someone help me ? this is my code:

```
<div class="application"   target="_blank" routerLink="/home">
    <img class="imgChart " src="./../assets/img/charts.jpg" alt="image 1">
    <div class="title-app">{{'STORE.APPSTAT' | translate}}</div>
    <p>{{'STORE.DESCRIPTIONSTATISTIQUE' | translate}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's basic html. Only `a` tag have the `_target` property. If you want a div to open into a blank page just add a `click` event that do that via ts

Comment: `onclick="window.open('http://google.com',  '_blank');"` you might use this way in javascript

Comment: @Nisarg not really a great idea when building Angular apps. Better having a method in your component class and binding the (click) of the element to that method

Comment: @nicowernli Agree with your point.

Comment: I am using a route inside my project not an external url how can i put an internal route inside the function window.open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open a window by calling the open method on the Window object and passing in a URL.

**Componenet.html:**

```
<div class="application" (click)='openNewTab()'>
    <img class="imgChart " src="./../assets/img/charts.jpg" alt="image 1">
    <div class="title-app">{{'STORE.APPSTAT' | translate}}</div>
    <p>{{'STORE.DESCRIPTIONSTATISTIQUE' | translate}}</p>
</div>
```

**Component.ts:**

```
  public openNewTab() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
  }
```

Comment: I am note using an url i am using a route inside my project

Comment: Pass in the URL of your project instead window.open('http ://www.yourproject.com/home ', '_blank');

Comment: @Mat Note that the new tab will be a completely new instance of your application, as if your user has navigated to that URL directly. This may or may not be what you want, Angular is an SPA framework and really isn't intended for this use-case

Comment: @Vlad274 is correct because its a new instance that means that any data or interaction your handled in the first instance wont be available in the second and vice-versa. Consider using a modal inside your application instead.

Comment: Thank you i will not use it

Comment: @Mat I did however answer your question, can you please accept my answer as it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Lamp, This is not fair to tell like this: please accept my answer and so. Be polite mate !

Comment: @Lamp thnk you too for your advice